# Reference the Form in a separate class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Forms project in Visual Studio 2012 (C#)

I have a class called Gameboard in my project, and I need to reference `this` in a method in that class. How can I reference the Form in another class??

EDIT:
@Sergey

```
public class Gameboard
{
    public Button[] buttonArray { get; set; }

    public Gameboard(int numberofButtons) //Constructor method that is referencing the App.config for the dimensions value to make the board
    {
        if (numberofButtons <= 0) 
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid Grid"); //throws an exception for an invalid grid size if dimensions is equal to or less than zero

        buttonArray = new Button[numberofButtons]; //creating an array the size of numberofButtons which is the dimensions value from App.config
        Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", 36.0f); //creates an instance of the Font class
        int sqrtY = (int) Math.Sqrt(numberofButtons);
        int z = 0; //Counter for array

        //Create the buttons for the form
        //Adds the buttons to the form first with null values then changes the .Text to ""
        for (int x = 0; x < sqrtY; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < sqrtY; y++)
            {
                buttonArray[z] = new Button();
                buttonArray[z].Font = font;
                buttonArray[z].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100);
                buttonArray[z].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100*y, 100*x);
                buttonArray[z].Click += new EventHandler(button_click);
                z++; 
            }
        }//At the end of this loop, buttonArray contains a number of buttons equal to Dimensions all of which have a .Text property of ""
    }
```

So there is plenty of other stuff after this in the Gameboard class, but so for the constructor I need to also pass in a Form instance? I'm just confused about the process.

Here is how I am called the constructor on the `Form_Load`

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Read the App.Config file to get the dimensions of the grid
            int dimensions = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dimensions"]);

            //Create the gameboard object with all the buttons needed
            Gameboard gb = new Gameboard(dimensions); //Calls the Gameboad constructor method

            //Add buttons to the form
            for (int x = 0; x < gb.buttonArray.Length; x++)
            {
                this.Controls.Add(gb.buttonArray[x]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: The answers below should give you enough pointers, you might want to consider a design pattern (MVC / MVVM) for designing a GUI application with a View (a UserControl representing the GameBoard) and a model (your GameBoard).

Answer (score 4):

Pass the `Form` instance as a parameter to `Gameboard` constructor or method call.

i.e. in Form code:

```
Gameboard gameboard = new Gameboard(this);
```

or

```
Gameboard gameboard = new Gameboard();
gameboard.MyMethod(this);
```

and in Gameboard:

```
public void MyMethod(Form mainForm)
{
    ... //Whatever
}
```

**UPDATE**

For your code it will be:

```
public class Gameboard
{
    ...
    public Gameboard(int numberofButtons, Form1 mainForm) //Constructor method that is referencing the App.config for the dimensions value to make the board
    {
        ... // init all buttons
        // for example
        for (int i = 0; i<buttonArray.Length; i++)
        {
            mainForm.Controls.Add(buttonArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

and in Form1_Load:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Read the App.Config file to get the dimensions of the grid
        int dimensions = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dimensions"]);

        //Create the gameboard object with all the buttons needed
        Gameboard gb = new Gameboard(dimensions, this); //Calls the Gameboad constructor method
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: please see below, i posted my Gameboard class constructor

Answer (score 1):

By passing the instance of your form as a reference to your `GameBoard` class. E.g. in your startup method of your application.

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        var mainForm = new Form1();
        var gameboard = new GameBoard(mainForm);
        Application.Run(mainForm);
    }
```